# Passive SMS receiver causing fatal error on receive

Tags: android, gps, sms

I have an app that checks for Last Known Location and if it is above a pre-defined threshold, it should suppress the notice of an incoming SMS as well as send an automatic reply to the sender.

When I test this between Emulators it fails with the following logcats:

```
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver biz.midl.drivereply.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: biz.midl.drivereply.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/biz.midl.drivereply-1.apk]
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: biz.midl.drivereply.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/biz.midl.drivereply-1.apk]
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)
11-28 09:07:03.747: E/AndroidRuntime(324):  ... 10 more
```

Here is my receiver Activity:

```
package biz.midl.drivereply;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class PassiveSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref= context.getSharedPreferences("chaosdriver", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int speedLimit = sharedPref.getInt("speedLimit", 5);
        String message = sharedPref.getString("message", "I'm sorry, but I am driving. I will text you when I am able!");

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        float currentSpeedms = lastKnownLocation.getSpeed();
        float currentSpeedMPH = (float) (currentSpeedms * 2.237);
        int newSpeed = (int) currentSpeedMPH;

        if (newSpeed > speedLimit)
        {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            if (extras == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            abortBroadcast();

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
            SmsMessage msg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);

            String origNumber = msg.getOriginatingAddress();

            onSend(origNumber, message);
        }
    }

    public void onSend(String px, String message)
    {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(px, null, message, null, null);
    }

}
```

Also, here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="biz.midl.drivereply"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.PassiveLocationChangedReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.PassiveSms"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_passive_sms" >
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.MyService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.MyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="biz.midl.drivereply.PassiveSMSSend"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_passive_smssend" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I ran a debug, but it's not showing my receiver steps/breakpoints.

Any suggestions on what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In my Manifest I had some capitalization issues. This resolved it.